# Using React.lazy with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to use React.lazy for code splitting in my TypeScript React app.

All I am doing is changing that line:

```
import {ScreensProductList} from "./screens/Products/List";
```

to this line:

```
const ScreensProductList = lazy(() => import('./screens/Products/List'));
```

But the `import('./screens/Products/List')` part triggers a TypeScript error, stating:

```
Type error: Type 'Promise<typeof import("/Users/johannesklauss/Documents/Development/ay-coding-challenge/src/screens/Products/List")>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<{ default: ComponentType<any>; }>'.
  Property 'default' is missing in type 'typeof import("/Users/johannesklauss/Documents/Development/ay-coding-challenge/src/screens/Products/List")' but required in type '{ default: ComponentType<any>; }'.
```

I am not quite sure what I am supposed to do here to get it to work.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You should do `export default class {...}` from the `./screens/Products/list` instead of `export class ScreensProductList {...}`.

Or, alternatively, you can do:

```
const ScreensProductList = lazy(() =>
  import('./screens/Products/List')
    .then(({ ScreensProductList }) => ({ default: ScreensProductList })),
);
```

Comment: That works perfectly. And how would I go about lazy loading multiple none default exports from a module? Do I have to do the second approach for each export?

Comment: @JohannesKlauß, yes, lazy() will only render a single component, so you have to repeat the wrapping for every one needed

Comment: That's really ugly. Especially since you can only have one default per module.

Comment: What types should be added to this for TypeScript?

Comment: @JamesHancock you can check out my answer, react-lazily solves multiple components per module `const { One, Two, Three } = lazily(() => import('./module'))`

Comment: @reggaeguitar this already has proper typescript types, you can see typescript example in https://codesandbox.io/s/react-lazily-vs-react-iqy23

Answer (score 11):

One option is to add default export in "./screens/Products/List" like that

```js
export default ScreensProductList;
```

Second is to change import code to

```js
const ScreensProductList = React.lazy(() =>
  import("./screens/Products/List").then((module) => ({
    default: module.ScreensProductList,
  }))
);
```

Or if you don't mind using an external library you could do:

```js
import { lazily } from 'react-lazily';
const { ScreensProductList } = lazily(() => import('./screens/Products/List'));
```

Answer (score 7):

Another solution would be:

#### 1. Import using lazy

```
const ScreensProductList = lazy(() => import('./screens/Products/List'));
```

#### 2. Set the type on the export

**React hooks**

```
import { FunctionComponent /*, FC */ } from 'react';

const List = () => (
  return </>;
);

export default List as FunctionComponent; // as FC;
```

**React class components**

```
import { Component, Fragment, ComponentType } from 'react';

class List extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Fragment />;
  }
}

export default List as ComponentType;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
const LazyCart = React.lazy(async () => ({ default: (await import('../Components/market/LazyCart')).LazyCart }))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the proper syntax. It works also in the Webstorm IDE (the other syntaxes shown here are still showing a warning)

```
const ScreensProductList = React.lazy(() => import("./screens/Products/List").then(({default : ScreensProductList}) => ({default: ScreensProductList})));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on this answer. This also works for the `dynamic` imports.

```
const Navbar = dynamic(() => import('../components/Navbar'), {
  ssr: false,
});
```

Where `Navbar` is a default exported component.

```
const Navbar = () => ()


export default Navbar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an index.ts file where you can export all your components like in this eg. :

```
export {default as YourComponentName} from "./YourComponentName";
```

After that you can use React.lazy:

```
React.lazy(() => import("../components/folder-name-where-the-index-file-is-created").then(({YourComponentName}) => ({default: YourComponentName})))
```