# React.lazy() with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I got the error :

> Property 'default' is missing in type 'Element' but required in type
>   '{ default: ComponentType; }'.ts(2322)

```
   {React.lazy(() => import(`../../i18n/locales/${this.props.lang}`).then(o => (
              <CustomSelects
                options={o.option}
                formattedMessageId="createroom_genre"
                value={this.props.genre}
                handleValueChange={this.handleGenreChange}
              />
            ))) }
```

I read [Using React.lazy with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54150819/using-react-lazy-with-typescript) but, I don't know how to do this in my case.

Let me know if you need more info.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Components shouldn't be declared in-place where they are used, this may kill optimizations and potentially result in infinite loop.

`React.lazy` is intended to be used with dynamic `import`, callback function is supposed to return a promise of a module, i.e. `{ default: Component }` object, but it currently returns a promise of React element.

`React.lazy` wasn't intended to be parameterized, it doesn't accept props and `this.props.lang` can't work there. It should be wrapped with another component to receive props:

```
const LocalCustomSelects = React.memo(({ lang }) => {
  const Lazy = React.lazy(async () => {
    const o = await import(`../../i18n/locales/${lang}`);
    return { default: props => <CustomSelects ... /> };
  });

  return <Lazy/>;
});
```

Comment: I tried but, Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]).

Comment: You tried it the wrong way then. There's no Promise child in the answer. It should work the way I listed. In case the problem persists, please, provide a way to replicate it.