# React.lazy warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
// project/src/App.js
import React, { Suspense, lazy } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import {NavBar, Loading} from "./components";
import './index.css';

const Home = lazy(() => import('./components/home'));

function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <NavBar/>
            <Suspense fallback={<Loading/>}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                    ...
                </Switch>
            </Suspense>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Other file.

```
// project/src/components/Home.js
import React from "react";

const Home = () => (
    <div className="home">
       ...
    </div>
);

export default Home;
```

The code works but `() => import('./components/home')` generates this **warning**:

*Argument type function(): Promise<{readonly default?: function(): any}> is not assignable to parameter type () => Promise<{default: ComponentType}>
Type Promise<{readonly default?: function(): any}> is not assignable to type Promise<{default: ComponentType}>*

I have already read the other topics and none of them work. Thank you.

Comment: isn't default import from "react" is React? Try to rename your lazy to React, and do React.lazy

Comment: import {lazy}  instead of lazy !

Comment: "import {lazy} instead of lazy !" tried, it doesn't work.

Comment: "isn't default import from "react" is React? Try to rename your lazy to React, and do React.lazy" tried, it doesn't work.

Comment: Just edited my answer for the error you're getting, check the stackoverflow answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I don't like to complicate things, to remove that warning you have to use this syntax:

```
const Home = lazy(() => import('./components/Home').then(({default: Home}) => ({default: Home})));
```

Answer (score 2):

lazy is not a default export from React. Try wrap it in curly braces like so:

```
import {lazy} from "react";
```

[Here's](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#route-based-code-splitting) how it's used

And incase it's Typescript shouting at you, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54150819/using-react-lazy-with-typescript)

Comment: I am not using Typescript, but still I found the solution in that link.
Reinier Garcia wrote: "https://stackoverflow.com/a/69180398/16981988"